# How does all 54bits after FE80/10 should be set to 0 apply?

Tags: ipv6, ip-link-local

I read on a website: " link local addresses use the address block of Fe80::/10 (from FE80:: to FE80:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF). However, the standard states that the 54 bits after FE80/10 should all be 0. so we won't see link local addresses begining with FE9, FEA or FEB. only FE8 "
I don't get it. if all the 54bits after /10 were set to 0s then We cannot have LLA address like this FE80:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF because the first 54 bits after the /10 should be set to 0 as they stated, so the correct form of the address should be FE80:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF . I'm I missing something simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [RFC4291 [2.5.6]](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.6):

```
|   10     |
|  bits    |         54 bits         |          64 bits           |
+----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
|1111111010|           0             |       interface ID         |
+----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
```

The first 10 bits are the global routing prefix. The next 54 bits are the subnet ID, which is all zero.

Answer (score 3):

`fe80::/10` is the prefix reserved for link-local addresses but only the single subnet `fe80::/64` is actually allocated for proper use.

> We cannot have LLA address like this `FE80:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF` because the first 54 bits after the /10 should be set to 0 as they stated, so the correct form of the address should be `FE80:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF`.

That is correct.